# Local Notification is not working when screen is locked

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications

i am using local notification in my app, when screen goes lock it is showing local notification in IOS- 5 but it is not working in below IOS say 4 .

any help please ?

Comment: could you please post the code you're using? might help understand the situation.

Comment: i think there is not any relation with code , it is showing notification in ios - 5 when screen is locked but not in ios 4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using the following code snippet on both iOS 4 and 5 and it works flawlessly, have a look and check your own code:

```
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    notification.alertBody = @"Local Message";
    notification.alertAction = @"View";
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    notification.fireDate = date;
    notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    [notification release];
```